# how do AppDelegate call ViewController.h

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm newbie that touch iOS dev recently, I follow [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_first_iphone_application.htm) and try to recognize structure from Xcode building with single view application.

But I find some issue that no relevant `ViewController.h` being imported in AppDelegate.h, and I know that the whole app's entry is `main.m` which call `AppDelegate.h`, and all my logic code is in `ViewController.h` etc.

**main.m**

[image]

**AppDelegate.h**

[image]

Maybe I can't describe clearly, I just really want to know that **how do AppDelegate call ViewController**?

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` .  You can access it anywhere in your app. Also, you don't need that to know about VC loading. See Paul's comment. You can however change the root Vc or starting point any time and change the flow ofVCs.

Comment: UIApplicationMain locates the initial scene from your storyboard (or initial NIB if using a NIB) and loads that - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW9 UIApplicztionMain calls your app delegate, the app delegate does not call the view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the main storyboard so you'll have to teach the AppDelegate how to call your ViewController. Here is a quick Swift code how to do so:

```
var window: UIWindow? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible() // this will take care of everything

    return true
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [ViewController new];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: OP has mentioned .h & .m files so he is clearly using objective-c. You should post your answer in the same language.

Comment: @NSNoob Sure he/she did, but I choose the answer code depending on tags. But only for you I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Main.storyboard or Main.xib (you can call this files with others names) file makes the viewController is window's rootViewController property.
If you change a ViewController class in your UI resource (xib or storyboard), then new viewController will be initialised.
To say to the application what file it should load, you use plist file and it's keys: UIMainStoryboardFile or NSMainNibFile.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1) you can read about structure of a ios application.

Answer (score -2):

`application.keyWindow.rootViewController` may be the ViewController